# What exactly is the 'potential' that is actualized in Aristotelian metaphysics?

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle, change

From my understanding, Aristotelian metaphysics uses the concepts of potentiality and actuality to explain change. Since being cannot come from non-being, when change occurs a potential is simply being actualized. However, what exactly is a potential, metaphysically speaking? What kind of substance is a potential, and what happens to it when it is actualized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentiality is not a substance. Substances are matter+form composites.

As St. Thomas Aquinas writes in his short word [*On The Principles of Nature*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DePrincNaturae.htm) 5.,

> everything which is in potency can be called matter
> <sub>*omne quod est in potentia potest dici materia*</sub>

Matter is a mode of being midway between non-existence and substance.

Comment: Okay, so when a change occurs, what exactly is the _thing_ that is changing? The reason why I thought potentiality was a thing is because I thought that's how Aristotle's was trying to solve the problem of change. Since I thought potentiality was a thing, it would solve the problem of being coming from non-being.

Comment: A substantial change (e.g., Na + Cl → NaCl, a frog becoming a human, etc.) involves two substances, the first of which is "corrupted" (reduced to primary matter) and the second of which is generated (primary matter informed with a substantial form); see [the diagram here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/30638/2014), [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/23065/2014), [this chapter on act & potency](https://www.ewtn.com/library/THEOLOGY/REALITY.HTM#05), or [_Aristotelian Definition of Motion \[=Change\]_](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3904).